# Null pointer exception that wasn't expected

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me why I am getting a null pointer exception here? I examined the code and haven't found anywhere that might be doing that, I'm a little stumped. Any help would be appreciated :D.

And by the way, the method is supposed to split strings between specified characters, for example: substringChars("sectionA; sectionB; sectionC;", ';'); would split the string between each semicolon (the specified character to split between) and return a string array with "sectionA" "sectonB" and "sectionC"

**Code:**

```
package substringChars;

public class SubstringChars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        substringChars("sectionA; sectionB; sectionC;", ';'); //There is an error on this line
        System.out.println(SubstringChars.output[0] + SubstringChars.output[1] + SubstringChars.output[2]);
    }
    public static String[] output;
    public static void substringChars(String iString, char sChar) {
        int pChar = 0, outputSlot = 0;
        char selectedChar;
        for(int i = 0; i <= iString.length(); i++) {
            selectedChar = iString.charAt(i);
            if(selectedChar == sChar) {
                if(i != iString.length()) {
                    SubstringChars.output[outputSlot] = (iString.substring(pChar, i)); //There is an error on this line
                }
                if(i == iString.length()) {
                    SubstringChars.output[outputSlot] = (String)(iString.substring(pChar));
                }
                pChar = i;
                outputSlot++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at substringChars.SubstringChars.substringChars(SubstringChars.java:16)
    at substringChars.SubstringChars.main(SubstringChars.java:5)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: any reason you can't use the debugger?

Comment: Also, there's a reason why line numbers are given in the stack trace.

Comment: Saw it.  Better to put the marker within the (admittedly too narrow) "window" of the code viewer.

Comment: Your problem is that the "output" array doesn't exist.  Simply declaring the reference is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your output array is never initialized.
2. Your for loop is counting past the bounds of 'iString'.

At the beginning of your `substringChars` method, add this:

```
output = new String[3];
```

And change your for loop to use < instead of <=.

```
for(int i = 0; i < iString.length(); i++) {
```

Also, I would recommend using a [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) while generating the list first, and then convert to a normal array after.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

There is a function in String called split(String regex) that does the same thing you are trying to do. you should use this unless you are for some reaosn trying to re-code the wheel.

```
String str = "hello;my;name;is;saigon"
String a[] = str.split(";")
// a[0] = "hello"
// a[1] = "my"
// a[2] = "name"
// ...
```

Comment: The standard approach in learning to program is through reinventing a few wheels.

Comment: Yes, what Dukeling said, exactly what I am trying to do. And thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

You are using uninitialized variable!

You have

```
public static String[] output;
```

which is never uninitialized and when you try to use it to store array, it is working with null (non-existent object).

This creates array of String for up to 1000 strings and store reference in variable output :

```
public static String[] output = new String[1000];
```

Comment: This is basically what elimirks said, but this will create 1000 slots in the output string when I only need iString.length() slots. Thanks for the reply :D

Answer (score 0):

Your Array output is null, since you have not initialized it,

Instead of

```
public static String[] output;
```

do

```
public static String[] output = new String[3];
```